# MOSEK Fusion API for Python: get number of feasible solutions found during optimization

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, mosek

I'm trying to access the number of feasible solutions found during MOSEK optimization. The reason for this is that we need to balance the parameters and stopping criteria between optimization time and quality (~ number of explored) solutions.

I'm using MOSEK Fusion API for Python (version 10.1.10).

I wasn't able to find any hints as how to do this in the documentation. Is there a way to access these found solutions (or access their number)?

Comment: If you want to have more complicated custom termination criteria you need to hook up a callback function like in https://docs.mosek.com/latest/pythonfusion/callback.html . It will be called, in particular, when the integer solution is improved. It is less cumbersome in the Optimizer API than in Fusion. Also, you can just set the parameter https://docs.mosek.com/latest/pythonfusion/parameters.html#mosek.iparam.mio_max_num_solutions to make the number of solutions found a stopping criterion.

Comment: The information item https://docs.mosek.com/latest/pythonfusion/constants.html#mosek.iinfitem.mio_num_int_solutions can be obtained after optimization